# Unity with C#: Changing sprite based on sprite sheet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My UI:

[image]

I have set up the health bar you see at the top. It is a sprite sheet with 3 indexes. Each with a different amount of hearts (3,2,1).

I have the health image shown above connected to the LoseCollider (C# script).

The goal:

When the ball drops onto the collider at the bottom of the screen instead of going to the lose screen the ball will reset to be attached to the paddle (until launch on click) and the health sprite will show 1 less heart until the 1 health sprite is on and then it will go to the lose screen.

The issue:

Right now I am trying to make it so that when the ball hits the lose collider (bottom of the screen) the sprite updates and the screen doesn't move the the "lose screen"

The code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this will work.
Set LoseCollider's gameobject tag to "LoseCollider"

```
GameObject player;

void Start()
{
    player = this.gameObject;
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "LoseCollider")
    {
        // Update the sprite
    }
}
```